# Utility representation of single peaked preferences

Tags: microeconomics, choice-theory, social-choice

Is it true that a single-peaked preference (with the peak at some finite point) over the set of real numbers, always has a utility representation ??

If yes, can you please hint towards the proof or references.

Is this result generalizable to multi-dimensional single-peakedness?

Comment: What are multi-dimensional single-peaked preferences?

Comment: By multi-dimensional single peakedness, I was referring to Bossert and Peters' paper titled "Single-peaked choice."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Basically, you can encode a form of [lexicographic preferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_preferences), probably the most familiar example of non-representable preferences, as single-peaked preferences on $\mathbb{R}$.

Define $\succeq$ so that $x\succeq y$ exactly if either $|x|<|y|$ or $|x|=|y|$ and $x\leq y$. Basically, the closer to the peak of $0$ a number is, the better, and in case of a tie, the number to the left of $0$ is better.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is a utility representation $v:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ of $\succeq$. For each $r\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$ (the strictly positive numbers), let $q_r$ be a rational number in the interval $\big(v(r),v(-r)\big)$. Since for $r\neq r'$, $\big(v(r),v(-r)\big)\cap\big(v(r'),v(-r')\big)=\emptyset$, we have an injection $r\mapsto q_r$ from $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, which is impossible since $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ is uncountable and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Comment: Did you mean $r\mapsto q_r$ for the injection from $\mathbb R_{++}$ to $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @HerrK. Yes; thank you for pointing it out.